# Python Champion Counter Program

Tags: python

I am having some issue with a  world_cup_champions.txt file.  When the program starts, it should read the text file and use a dictionary to store the required data using the name of each country that has won the World Cup as the key.  I can not get to display the "Years" to the user. Here is a sample of the text files:

```
Year,Country,Coach,Captain
1930,Uruguay,Alberto Suppici,José Nasazzi
1934,Italy,Vittorio Pozzo,Gianpiero Combi
1938,Italy,Vittorio Pozzo,Giuseppe Meazza
1950,Uruguay,Juan López,Obdulio Varela
1954,Germany,Sepp Herberger,Fritz Walter
1958,Brazil,Vicente Feola,Hilderaldo Bellini
1962,Brazil,Aymoré Moreira,Mauro Ramos
1966,England,Alf Ramsey,Bobby Moore
```

And the code:

```
def winners():
    f2 = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")

    dict_values ={}
    temp_list = []
    tmp_list1 = []
    tmp_list2 = []

    for l in f2:
        temp_list.append(l.strip())



    for val in temp_list:
        tmp_val = val.split(',')
        if tmp_val[1] not in dict_values:
            dict_values[tmp_val[1]] = 1
        else:
            dict_values[tmp_val[1]] += 1


    for key,value in dict_values.items():
        tmp_list2.append([key, value])
        tmp_list2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])



    for val in tmp_list2:

        print(" " + val[0].ljust(14)  + " " + str(val[1]))




def main():


    print("FIFA World Cup Winners")
    print()
    print(" Country".ljust(14) + " Wins".center(9)  + "Years".rjust(14))
    print("{:15} {:5}".format("="*8, "="*5))

    winners()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Both the formatting of the file, and the code need fixing to be able to help more effectively

Comment: I have formatted things as well as I can

Comment: Look into the `csv` library - it seems perfect for processing data like this

Answer (score 3):

It's a CSV file, why not use a CSV reader?

```py
import csv

def read_data(filename):
    wins = {}
    with open(filename) as filehandle:
        reader = csv.reader(filehandle)
        next(reader)  # skip header
        for row in reader:
            year, country, coach, captain = row
            if country not in wins:
                wins[country] = []
            wins[country].append([year, coach, captain])
    return wins
```

This gives you a nice dict with country names and keys and `[year, coach, captain]` lists as values.

Then you can do:

```py
def print_winners(data):
    for country, wins in data.items():
        num_wins = len(wins)
        years = [win[0] for win in wins]
        print(country, num_wins, ', '.join(years))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I parsed it. Tried to make this function as educational as possible. If you want to explore it deeply, I suggest you take a look at [Panda's documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and learn how to really parse large and dense CSV files

```
 def parse(path_to_file):
    from_file = open(path_to_file, "r").read()
    ret = []
    keys, splitted = from_file.split("\n")[0].split(","), from_file.split("\n")[1:]
    for data in splitted:
        if not data: continue
        s = data.split(",")
        print(s, keys)
        q = zip(keys, s)
        ret.append(dict(q))
    return ret

parsed_dicts = parse("path_to_your_txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the very useful csv module, here is your code with some variables named better, and working, but not nicely formatted output.

```
def winners():
    f2 = open("world_cup_champions.txt","r+")

    total_wins = {}
    years = {}
    lines = []
    country_list = []

    for line in f2:
        lines.append(line.strip())

    # Skip the first line with [1:]
    for line in lines[1:]:
        values = line.split(',')
        country = values[1]
        year = values[0]
        if country not in total_wins:
            total_wins[country] = 1
            years[country] = [year]
            country_list.append(country)
        else:
            total_wins[country] += 1
            years[country].append(year)


    for country in country_list:
        wins = total_wins[country]
        year_list = years[country]
        print(" " + country.ljust(14)),
        print(" " + str(wins)),
        print(year_list)

def main():


    print("FIFA World Cup Winners")
    print()
    print(" Country".ljust(14) + " Wins".center(9)  + "Years".rjust(14))
    print("{:15} {:5}".format("="*8, "="*5))

    winners()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The way you were doing it, you were putting the wrong info into your only dictionary. You need a different data type to hold a string, an integer, and a list of integers. You could make the value of the dictionary into a list that holds both the total number of wins, and the list of years, alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

Some food for thought:

```
import pandas as pd

def main():

    df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
    print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output

```
   Year  Country            Coach             Captain
0  1930  Uruguay  Alberto Suppici        José Nasazzi
1  1934    Italy   Vittorio Pozzo     Gianpiero Combi
2  1938    Italy   Vittorio Pozzo     Giuseppe Meazza
3  1950  Uruguay       Juan López      Obdulio Varela
4  1954  Germany   Sepp Herberger        Fritz Walter
5  1958   Brazil    Vicente Feola  Hilderaldo Bellini
6  1962   Brazil   Aymoré Moreira         Mauro Ramos
7  1966  England       Alf Ramsey         Bobby Moore
```

Comment: Thank You, for your all of your help. I have learn a lot from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, using dictionary and lists expressions (in the same fashion you can print the coaches and captains):

```
def winners():
    # read file 
    with open("file.txt","r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # init dict
    dict_values = {}

    # process
    for line in lines[1:]:
        year    = line.split(",")[0]
        country = line.split(",")[1]        
        coach   = line.split(",")[2]
        captain = line.split(",")[3]     

        # fill in dict
        if not(country in dict_values.keys()):
            dict_values[country] = [[year, coach, captain]]

        else: 
            dict_values[country].append([year, coach, captain])

    # sort dict
    sorted_list = sorted(dict_values.items(),
                         key = lambda x: len(x[1]),
                         reverse = True)

    # printing
    for country, values in sorted_list:
        years    = [value[0] for value in values]
        coaches  = [value[1] for value in values]
        captains = [value[2] for value in values]
        print(" " + country.ljust(16) \
              + " " + str(len(years)).ljust(10) + " "  \
              + str(years).replace('[', "").replace(']', "").replace("'", ""))


def main():
    # printing
    print("FIFA World Cup Winners")
    print()
    print(" Country".ljust(14) + " Wins".center(9)  + "Years".rjust(14))
    print("{:15} {:11} {:}".format("="*9, "="*6, "="*12))

    winners()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
 Country         Wins           Years
=========       ======      ============
 Uruguay          2          1930, 1950
 Italy            2          1934, 1938
 Brazil           2          1958, 1962
 Germany          1          1954
 England          1          1966
```